# Post-tessellation Vertex Function and Raytracing: Getting More Detailed Geometries for the Acceleration Structures

Tags: swift, metal

I have recently gained some interest in the raytracing API provided by the Metal framework. I understand that you can attach a vertex buffer to a geometry descriptor that Metal will use to create the acceleration structure later (on a `MTLPrimitiveAccelerationStructureDescriptor` instance for example).

This made me wonder if it were possible to write the output of the tessellator into a separate vertex buffer from the post-tessellation vertex shader and pass that along to the raytracer. I thought that perhaps you could get more detailed geometry and still render without rasterization. For example, I might have the following simple post-tessellation vertex function:

```
[[patch(triangle, 3)]]
vertex FunctionOutIn tessellation_vertex_triangle(PatchIn patchIn [[stage_in]],
                                                  float3 patch_coord [[ position_in_patch ]])
{
    // Barycentric coordinates
    float u = patch_coord.x;
    float v = patch_coord.y;
    float w = patch_coord.z;

    // Convert to cartesian coordinates
    float x = u * patchIn.control_points[0].position.x + v * patchIn.control_points[1].position.x + w * patchIn.control_points[2].position.x;
    float y = u * patchIn.control_points[0].position.y + v * patchIn.control_points[1].position.y + w * patchIn.control_points[2].position.y;

    // Output
    FunctionOutIn vertexOut;
    vertexOut.position = float4(x, y, 0.0, 1.0);
    vertexOut.color = half4(u, v, w, 1.0h);
    return vertexOut;
}
```

However, the following doesn't compile

```
// Triangle post-tessellation vertex function
[[patch(triangle, 3)]]
vertex void tessellation_vertex_triangle(device void *outputBuffer [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                         PatchIn patchIn [[stage_in]],
                                         float3 patch_coord [[ position_in_patch ]])
{
    // Barycentric coordinates
    float u = patch_coord.x;
    float v = patch_coord.y;
    float w = patch_coord.z;
    
    // Convert to cartesian coordinates
    float x = u * patchIn.control_points[0].position.x + v * patchIn.control_points[1].position.x + w * patchIn.control_points[2].position.x;
    float y = u * patchIn.control_points[0].position.y + v * patchIn.control_points[1].position.y + w * patchIn.control_points[2].position.y;
    
    // Output
    FunctionOutIn vertexOut;
    vertexOut.position = float4(x, y, 0.0, 1.0);
    vertexOut.color = half4(u, v, w, 1.0h);
}
```

But I noticed that the function doesn't compile when I don't use the data in the control points as output, like so

```
[[patch(triangle, 3)]]
vertex FunctionOutIn tessellation_vertex_triangle(PatchIn patchIn [[stage_in]],
                                                  float3 patch_coord [[ position_in_patch ]])
{
    // Barycentric coordinates
    float u = patch_coord.x;
    float v = patch_coord.y;
    float w = patch_coord.z;

    // Convert to cartesian coordinates
    float x = u * patchIn.control_points[0].position.x + v * patchIn.control_points[1].position.x + w * patchIn.control_points[2].position.x;
    float y = u * patchIn.control_points[0].position.y + v * patchIn.control_points[1].position.y + w * patchIn.control_points[2].position.y;

    // Output
    FunctionOutIn vertexOut;

    // Does not use x or y (and therefore the `patch_control_point<T>`'s values
    // are not used as output into the rasterizer)
    vertexOut.position = float4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
    vertexOut.color = half4(1.0h, 1.0h, 1.0h, 1.0h);
    return vertexOut;
}
```

I looked at the `patch_control_point<T>` template that was publicly exposed but didn't see anything enforcing this. What is going on here?

In particular, how would I go about increasing the quality of the geometry into the raytracer? Would I simply have to use more complex assets? Tessellation has its place in the rasterization pipeline, but can it be used elsewhere?